# Simultaneously send to beamer via HDMI or VGA and share screen in videoconference

Tags: ipad, hdmi, vga-adapter, projector, video-conference

My aim is to deliver a conference to people present in the lecture room and also to those attending from home; all this at the same time. I am on Ipad 6th generation - iOS 14.2

Using the Apple Lightning to Digital AV Adapter and HDMI, it is apparently not possible to simultaneously project through a beamer and share the screen for people at home. I deduce that the direct connection with an HDMI cable already uses  AirPlay and this thus hinders the possibility for screen sharing.
The use of third party apps, such as SmartMirror TV & Device app, is not an option for me since I can't share the same network.

I was just wondering whether:

- using **HDMI** is definetely not doable
- using a **VGA** connection (through an Apple Lightning to VGA Adapter) could solve the problem, allowing simultaneous projection in lecture room and broadcast for students at home.

Comment: Do you have access to other devices such as a Mac computer?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have only a PC, that is connected to a different network, which I do not have access to.

Comment: the VGA connection works with Ipad Pro, but not with Ipad 6th generation. No clue if it would work with Ipad Air or more recent basic Ipads